# Hello, i am from iraq and i have iraqian passport, but i have Romanian visa for 45days to stay. problem may be happened during this travel?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, iraqi-citizens

But in reality i want to go to hungary to Austria  by train, what problem may be happened to me during this travel in check control?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can get to Austria (on topic), or whether you can stay in Austria as an asylum seeker (off topic)?

Comment: I can stay at romania for 45 days as i have got Romanian visa but i want to visit Hungary during my trip? Can i enter Hungary with iraqian passport? Thanks

Comment: Hungary (and Austria) are part of the *Schengen Zone*. You will need a Schengen visa -- different from a Romanian one -- to enter or transit if you are traveling on an Iraqi passport.

Comment: Yeah you're right but i want to go Hungary as an immigration ,i dont have time and money to get Hungary visa . did u get me ? illegally

Comment: There are border controls and you will require a visa to pass them. We can't provide advice on how to sneak into Hungary illegally. If you have a specific question about how to obtain that visa, please ask it as a new question. If you qualify as a refugee and plan to seek protection, you're going to be better off with somewhere that provides special advice for refugees, as we can't provide legal advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for advice on how to enter the Schengen area illegally.

Comment: Yeah mine question is ,can i enter Hungary with iraqian passport and brought romanian visa _?

Comment: No. You need a Schengen visa. A Romanian visa is not sufficient for entering Hungary.

Comment: Thanks but what other countries that i can enter by Romanian visa ?how romanian people can enter Hungary without any problem?

Comment: That is a different question, @Kingofh . A Romanian visa doesn't mean you get treated like a Romanian when travelling. You're still treated as an Iraqi passport holder, with the restrictions that kind of passport holds. If you would like to know where you can travel as an Iraqi passport holder with a Romanian visa, that is a perfectly good question and you should [Ask it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Yeah i want to know where i can travel as an iraqi passportholder with a romanian visa ?